# 12v line is showing up to 14v in BIOS (DMM reading are fine)

Tags: motherboard, bios, power-supply, voltage

Purely by chance, upon rebooting, in the BIOS, I saw that 12v line was showing 13.9v, although I used the computer normally all day long.
After resetting all settings in the BIOS and reboot, nothing changed (in AIDA64 as well). I looked at the capacitors on the mother board, checked the cables connections, everything seems to be in order. Until today, I used the computer quite intensively the last month and everything was ok.

After that, I turned it off and pulled it out of the socket for about 4 hours. As I turned it on, the BIOS showed 12.9 - 13.2. Rebooting to  Windows, AIDA64 showed 12.

For the first 90 of AIDA's stress test everything seemed to be stable, and then again 12v line started to crawl up. I stopped the test at 12.55v, but even after that it jumped to 12.6v.

I tested with a DMM, all three lines are ok

- 3.3v - 3.33-3.34
- 5v - 5-5.08
- 12v - 12.07 - 12.08

Now here is the question. How dangerous is it to continue to use the motherboard?
If sensors malfunctioning, then there is no need to change anything.

- Board - ASUS x370 Prime Pro
- Processor - Ryzen 2700x
- Power Supply - Corsair TX650m 80 Plus Gold

The circuit board and the block are two years old by force. Both were bought new. The only detail, the computer stood for about 10 months without turning on due to the lack of a video card.

Comment: What sensors exactly do you believe are malfunctioning?

Comment: @Ramhound Well, that which are responsible for 12v rail readings. Or MB is pumping the voltage up?

Comment: It is important to keep in mind that voltage readings from the motherboard should not be relied upon. If you think something is wrong the voltage, get a PSU tester.

Comment: You have reset the firmware to rule out an accidental overclock?

Comment: I used DMM (tester) and stated that results are fine. First thing that I done was resetting BIOS.

Comment: There's no reason for concern. 12 V is used primarily by peripherals, such as an HDD, which may have high current demand during spin-up, so a trifle higher voltage before the HDD runs is OK. If it's working, then don't worry.